# creating a new contract inside a contract, what is happening

Tags: ethereum, solidity

This might be a beginner question, but the thing is confusing

I can see from samples like bellow
https://github.com/acloudfan/Blockchain-Course-Basic-Solidity/blob/93ca256bcf8c436c144425291257dcff5c3b269f/test/TestMetacoin.sol#L18

```
MetaCoin meta = new MetaCoin();
```

That a contract can be created/instantiated inside another contract, I want to understand what is happening here? does this create a new contract and deploy, therefore having a new address? or does it works or behaves like an ordinary class like in C++ or java, etc?

I dont know what is the context of the meta instance at this point.

Can someone help explain?

Secondly, this might be related,
What does it mean when two contracts are defined in a single Sol file and the second contract instantiated the first one like below?

```
pragma solidity 0.4.21;

contract Base {

    uint public dataA;
    bytes32 public dataB;

    function setAB(uint a, bytes32 b) public {
        dataA = a;
        dataB = b;
    }

    function getA() public view returns(uint) {
        return dataA ;
    }

    function getB() public view returns(bytes32) {
        return dataB ;
    }

}

contract Extra {

   Base base;

   function Extra() public {
       base = new Base();
   }

   ...
}
```

Does the contract base deployed and will have its own address?

Comment: Yes, it will have its own address. It's different from using new to create a struct or an array.